# Analogy of spherical and hyperbolic geometry projection

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I have heard of the following analogy:

- The **Poincare disc model** of the hyperbolic plane is analogous to the **stereographic projection** of the sphere, and
- The **Beltrami-Klein model** of the hyperbolic plane is analogous to the **gnomonic projection** of the sphere.

Is it possible to make this connection more rigorous? Perhaps by exploiting some kind of trick, like considering the hyperbolic plane a "sphere of imaginary radius"? If so, is there an analogous spherical-geometry projection for the Poincare half-plane model of the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: The Poincare disk model and the stereographic projection preserve angles (i.e. they are conformal). The Beltrami-Klein model and the gnomonic projection preserve geodesics (i.e. they map geodesics to straight lines).

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$If $P$ is a plane in $\Reals^{3}$ and $c$ is a point not on $P$, define *projection to $P$ with center $c$* to be the map that sends each point $x \not\in P$ to $\overline{cx} \cap P$, the point where the line from $c$ to $x$ crosses $P$.

The table below gives a quantitative analogy, in which $(x, y, z)$ denote Cartesian coordinates and the columns are related by the Wick rotation $(x, y) \mapsto i(x, y)$:
$$
\begin{array}{l|ll}
  & \text{Elliptic} & \text{Hyperbolic} \\
  \hline
  \text{Plane} & x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 1 & -(x^{2} + y^{2}) + z^{2} = 1,\ z > 0 \\
  \text{Gnomonic} & c = (0, 0, 0),\ P = \{z = 1\} & c = (0, 0, 0),\ P = \{z = 1\} \\
  \text{Conformal} & c = (0, 0, -1),\ P = \{z = 0\} & c = (0, 0, -1),\ P = \{z = 0\} \\
\end{array}
$$

To expand the analogy:

- The center of [gnomonic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection) of the unit sphere is the center (i.e., the origin), and maps each open hemisphere (for example, the "northern hemisphere" $\{z > 0\}$) onto the tangent plane at the "center" (here, the point $(0, 0, 1)$).

  The center of gnomonic projection for the hyperbolic plane is the origin (the "center" of sorts for the hyperboloid of two sheets), and the image of projection is the open unit disk.

  As Rahul notes, the geodesics of each plane model are the intersections of the corresponding unit sphere with a plane through the origin; projection from the origin consequently sends geodesics to lines (or line segments).
- The center of [conformal projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) of the unit sphere is a point of tangency (e.g., the "south pole" $(0, 0, -1)$), and the image plane is the "orthogonal plane" through the center (here, $\{z = 0\}$).

  The center of conformal projection for the hyperbolic plane can also be taken to be $(0, 0, -1)$, not a point of the hyperbolic plane, but the "antipode of the center $(0, 0, 1)$", lying on the bottom sheet, and the image of projection is again the open unit disk.

The two gnomonic projections, and stereographic projection of the sphere, are readily-visualized. Probably the least well-known projection is the conformal projection from the hyperbolic plane to the unit disk in the plane $\{z = 0\}$, using $c = (0, 0, -1)$:

[image: Projecting the hyperboloid to the disk]

Comment: [+1] very good explanations.

Comment: added buits to  the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model with reference to thie question hope you all agree

Comment: @Willemien: Thank you; I learned of these constructions from [_Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometry_](http://www.cas.uab.edu/mathrr/Export/details/5173.html) by [Pat Ryan](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~pjr/), which probably contains an authoritative bibliography. I'd be surprised if these results weren't well-known by the end of the 19th Century.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a full answer, but it is the only way I can include graphical information which comes from p. 426 of a French book.

I think this figure is self-explanatory.

If you read French, this (excellent) book is "Initiation à la géométrie" by Daniel LEHMANN and Rudolphe BKOUCHE, Presses Universitaires de France,1988.

[image]